# JDBC Call to Oracle Stored Function - IN parameter of type "table of struct"

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, stored-functions

I have a complex PL/SQL stored function and I have to call this function in JAVA.
Here is the procedure :

```
FUNCTION SUB_REPORT_INCOMPLETE(p_ACT_ID IN ACTIVITIES.ID%TYPE,
                               p_MISSING TO_SUB_MISSING) RETURN VARCHAR2;
```

So, as you can see here, the type of my second parameter is **TO_SUB_MISSING** which is  a table of **O_SUB_MISSING** :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TO_SUB_MISSING AS TABLE OF O_SUB_MISSING;
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE O_SUB_MISSING AS OBJECT (ACT_ID NUMBER, GIT_ID NUMBER, MISSING_QTY NUMBER);
```

After some researchs, I write this code :

```
Context context = new InitialContext();
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup(dataSourceName);
connection = dataSource.getConnection();

StructDescriptor structDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("O_SUB_MISSING", connection);
STRUCT[] structs = new STRUCT[listPieces.size()];
int ind = 0;
for (PieceEntity piece : listPieces) {
    Object[] params = new Object[3];
    params[0] = piece.getActId();
    params[1] = piece.getGitId();
    params[2] = piece.getMissingQty();
    STRUCT struct = new STRUCT(structDescriptor, connection, params);
    structs[ind++] = struct;
}
ArrayDescriptor desc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("TO_SUB_MISSING", connection);

statement = connection.prepareCall(Constants.DECLARE_INCOMPLETE_MODUL);
statement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
statement.setLong(2, agmId);
statement.setArray(3, new ARRAY(desc, connection, structs));
statement.executeQuery();
```

But with this code I get an exception on the *StructDescriptor.createDescriptor* line :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
```

I try to solve this exception with two solutions I find on some *stackoverflow* post but it didn't work.

**Solution 1 :**

```
    OracleConnection oraConn = (OracleConnection) new DelegatingConnection(connection).getInnermostDelegate();
```

**Solution 2 :**

```
    OracleConnection oraConn = connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
```

The first solution throw the same exception and the second throw the following exception :

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.unwrap(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

Have you an idea of how I can solve my issue ?

Comment: For solution 1 have you set `accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true"` in the context config?

Comment: I have try to add ths in the context.xml of my tomcat server :
`<parameter>
    <name>accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed</name>
    <value>true</value>
</parameter>`
But it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Not a concrete solution but it’s a hint : https://community.oracle.com/thread/718072?tstart=832
May be this will help you to resolve your issue.